# Convert duplicates to nan keeping only last occurrence

Tags: python, indexing, duplicates

Trying to create new column `last_visit_idx` that displays the index row number of the last visit by each visitor. However, I am wanting that this value only appear in the actual row of the last visit by the said visitor.
Please see below what I am have come up with so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, date, time



df  = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2017-07-02 09:00:00', '2017-07-03 15:00:00', '2018-04-05 15:00:00', 
                                    '2018-12-20 11:00:00', '2019-01-06 14:00:00', '2020-09-06 17:00:00']})


df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

df['visitor'] = ['Dave', 'Dave', 'Dave', 'Peter', 'Peter', 'rob']

df['last_visit_idx'] = np.searchsorted(df.visitor, df.visitor, side='right')

df.loc[df.duplicated(['last_visit_idx','visitor']), 'last_visit_idx'] = np.nan

df['last_visit_idx'] = np.where(df['last_visit_idx'] > 0, pd.to_numeric(df['last_visit_idx']) - 1, np.nan)
```

The current code produces the following:

```
                 date visitor  last_visit_idx
0 2017-07-02 09:00:00    Dave             2.0
1 2017-07-03 15:00:00    Dave             NaN
2 2018-04-05 15:00:00    Dave             NaN
3 2018-12-20 11:00:00   Peter             4.0
4 2019-01-06 14:00:00   Peter             NaN
5 2020-09-06 17:00:00     rob             5.0
```

The aim is to achieve the following:

```
                 date visitor  last_visit_idx
0 2017-07-02 09:00:00    Dave             NaN
1 2017-07-03 15:00:00    Dave             NaN
2 2018-04-05 15:00:00    Dave             2.0
3 2018-12-20 11:00:00   Peter             NaN
4 2019-01-06 14:00:00   Peter             4.0
5 2020-09-06 17:00:00     rob             5.0
```

Please can I get some much needed guidance.

Comment: You could reverse the data.

Comment: using `df = df.iloc[::-1].reset_index(drop=True)`? because that didn't work for me